# Read multiple rows indexed by a series of merged cells from Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, apache-poi

I am trying to read an Excel file using Apache POI. My problem is trying to read a series of rows as a merged cell, taking into account that the number of rows that this merge contains is arbitrary.

This picture

[image]

might be an adequate example, I'm hoping. In this case, I can't come up with a function to through all the rows that are Attributes and stopping when I reach the Foreign Keys rows. The "Attributes" string in the merged cells is contained in the very first row of the merged cells.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cells in a merged region appear in the spreadsheet XML. and the rows and cells can be read. But their cell type is missing from the XML. In POI, the cell type comes back as `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`. This could be caused by other things though so it is not enough just to look for `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`. You also need to check to see if a cell falls within one of the merge regions in the sheet.  You can do that like this:

```
public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(Cell cell) {
    Sheet sheet = cell.getSheet();
    for (CellRangeAddress range : sheet.getMergedRegions()) {
        if (range.isInRange(cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex())) {
            return range;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will return either a `CellRangeAddress` object that contains the cell, or a null. Then you can use

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
            CellRangeAddress range = getMergedRegion(cell);
            if (range != null) {
                Cell mergeValue = sheet.getRow(range.getFirstRow()).getCell(range.getFirstColumn());
                System.out.println("Cell " + cell.getAddress() + ": " + "merged cell (" + 
                    range.formatAsString() + ") " + mergeValue.getStringCellValue());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Cell " + cell.getAddress() + ": " + "blank");
            }
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            System.out.println("Cell " + cell.getAddress() + ": " + cell.getStringCellValue());                 
        }
    }
}
```

to get the values in the cells in the sheet. You may need to process numeric or boolean cells, those are not shown in my example.

Answer (score 0):

And what exactly are you struggling with? If you need to read the content of the merged cells you might want to check [this thread](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Reading-Merged-Cells-td2312592.html). If your Question is "how do I determine that there is a merged region in the row (e.g. your "Checks"-Row) you will not get around putting some kind of "insight"-Logic into your parser, like "if col A == 'Checks', then read col C"